# Invalid operands to binary expression cout problem

Tags: c++, cout

```
void Basket_LinkedList::print_cookies() const{
    cout<<"**********cookies' basket**********"<<endl;
    //list<Cookie> basket_list;
    for (auto it=basket_list.begin(); it!=basket_list.end(); it++) {
        if (it->get_size()==Cookie::CookieSize::small) {
            //cout<<*it<<endl;
        }
    }
    cout<<"**********cookies' basket**********"<<endl;
}
```

I got errors with the line mark as `//`, for the first one:

```
(Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream')
(aka 'basic_ostream<char>')
```

and second error is:

```
'const std::__1::__list_const_iterator<Cookie, void *>::value_type'
(aka 'const Cookie')))
```

Can someone explain and help to fix it?

Comment: the problem is the second // one , cout<<*it<<endl;

Comment: Do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of errors pop up when the compiler it stating it does not know how to use the insertion operator `<<` with the types you've given it.  Defining a function like the following would help you.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Cookie& c){
    out << c.some_field;
    return out;
}
```